# Invalid use of Null when explicitly assigning Null to a variable of type variant

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently trying to upgrade an old ADP project from Access 2010 x64 to Access 2019 x64. I have managed to convert it to an .accdb file, but are now running into errors with my VBA code.

Please consider the following function:

```
Public Function GetSystemSetting(sKey As String, vValue As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim cnTemp As ADODB.Connection, rsTemp As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim sSQL As String
  On Error GoTo LAB_Error
  sSQL = "SELECT T_Value FROM INT_SystemSettings WHERE (T_Key = '" & sKey & "')"
  Set cnTemp = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rsTemp = New ADODB.Recordset
  cnTemp.CursorLocation = adUseServer
  cnTemp.Open CurrentProject.BaseConnectionString
  rsTemp.Open sSQL, cnTemp, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
  If (rsTemp.EOF) Then GoTo LAB_Error
  vValue = Nz(rsTemp![T_Value])
  rsTemp.Close
  cnTemp.Close
  On Error GoTo 0
  GetSystemSetting = True
  Exit Function
LAB_Error:
  vValue = Null
  If (rsTemp.State <> adStateClosed) Then rsTemp.Close
  If (cnTemp.State <> adStateClosed) Then cnTemp.Close
  GetSystemSetting = False
End Function
```

I know that this code is questionable in many aspects, but would like to focus on the line

```
vValue = Null
```

When this line gets executed, a runtime error is raised:

```
Invalid use of Null
```

I have read dozens of articles about that error message on various sites, including this one, but it always boiled down to that the OP hadn't made the destination variable a `variant`. But in my case, the destination variable, vValue, ***is*** of type `variant`. Furthermore, that code ran since 8 years without any problem in Access 2010 x64.

What is the reason for that error, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: How are you calling this function? `vValue` isn't a local variable, it is (ByRef) the variable from the calling function, which is not necessarily a Variant.

Comment: And another thing, you could replace this whole function with a simple `DLookup` call.

Comment: @Andre Thank you very much! That was the problem ... not sure how I could miss it (my last VBA coding is several years back ...). Regarding `DLookup`, I'm not sure if it does the locking exactly as the original author of the function intended; in general, I'd like to change as less as possible in this beast (LOTS of code in there ...). Would you mind making your comments an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to remember that with functions like this:

```
Public Function GetSystemSetting(sKey As String, vValue As Variant) As Boolean
    vValue = Null
```

unless you specify `ByVal`, the parameters are passed `ByRef`, and so you are actually writing to the variable that is used as parameter when calling the function.

If that variable isn't a variant, the error is triggered.

```
Dim str As String
If GetSystemSetting("non-existing", str) Then    ' KA-BOOM!
```

---

An alternative with `DLookup` would be the following. It should behave exactly the same, unless you have valid SystemSettings that are NULL.

```
Public Function GetSystemSetting(sKey As String, vValue As Variant) As Boolean
  ' DLookup returns NULL if no record is found
  vValue = DLookup("T_Value", "INT_SystemSettings", "T_Key = '" & sKey & "'")
  GetSystemSetting = Not IsNull(vValue)
End Function
```

`DLookup` is a read-only operation, so it should be the same regarding locking.